# unable to execute perl script

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and want to plot a chart using Excel. I found some code, but when I tried to execute it, it only shows "Press any key to continue..." on the command prompt. The code is executable by others. I also tried to download the Excel writer pack and placed them in the lib folder, but it isn't executing at all. The code is found definitely executable.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new('chart.xlsx');
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

# Add the worksheet data the chart refers to.
my $data = [
    ['Category', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    ['Value',    1, 4, 5, 2, 1, 5],
];
$worksheet->write('A1', $data);

# Add a worksheet chart.
my $chart = $workbook->add_chart(type => 'column');

# Configure the chart.
$chart->add_series(
    categories => '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7',
    values     => '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7',
);
__END__
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: do you see the file it supposed to create?

Comment: "placed them in the lib folder" - that's not the proper way to install perl packages.. (though it had to see some error messages if something went wrong) do some google-ing.

Comment: What does "executable by others" actually mean? You get the Excel file created in another machine?

Comment: the code works on my machine, just installed Excel::Writer::XLSX via cpan and it ran great

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, may i know how should i add the packages in?

Comment: @m0skit0 its a code shared by someone in the net

Comment: @HaraldBrinkhof how do u install this excel::writer::xlsx?

Comment: [Use cpan or install by hand](https://www.google.com/search?q=calling+C+libraries+from+jaba&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs#hl=en&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&sclient=psy-ab&q=perl+install+library&oq=perl+install+library&aq=f&aqi=g1g-K1g-mK1g-bK1&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i30j0i5i30j0i8i30.319012.324945.4.325258.43.24.11.8.12.0.246.3162.8j14j2.24.0...0.0.13qHesmB_5Q&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=fb4c575ddcccef5a&biw=1600&bih=753)

Comment: i typed this cpan App::cpanminus and it tells me its up to date.. do i need to download or install something else?

Comment: What operation system are you an? Windows, Linux or Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what Oleg means by his answer:

Depending on the operation system you're on, your way to call the perl program might look a little different. This it what it looks like for me.

simbabque@box:~> perl xsltest.pl 
   simbabque@box:~>

Now if you're not sure where your working directory is, edit the code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
use Cwd;                 # <--- new line!
print cwd(), "\n";       # <--- new line!
```

Now when you run your program, it should print something like this:

```
simbabque@box:~> perl xsltest.pl 
/home/simbabque/
simbabque@box:~>
```

In my case, the working directory is the one I'm calling perl from. It could be another one, though.

Although it does not print anything to the screen, it should have created the file called `chart.xlsx` in my working directory. I can look for it with `ls` on the command line, or say `file chart.xlsx` to see if it is inded an Excel file.

```
simbabque@box:~> file chart.xlsx
chart.xlsx: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

I could now open it in Excel or Libre Office.

---

If you are on Windows, open an Explorer and point it to where the `cwd` function has said. There you can double-click your file to open it in Excel. If it is the same folder as the program you could also use the open dialogue of your text editor, right-click on `chart.xlsx` and click *open* instead of *select*.

Answer (score 1):

It is executing. You build Excel table in file somewhere without printing anything to screen. "Press any key to continue..." prompt is printed by your system when your script successfully finishes. If you're not sure where is your script working directory is located you can use `Cwd` module to check it. Also make sure that working directory is writable for you.

Comment: i dont understand.. sorry. i'm very new to this program.